# Error "1132148 is not a hash" when running Perl program in Linux using Tk

Tags: linux, perl, hash, x11, tk-toolkit

I'm running Centos 7, Perl 5 and X11.  In running a first time perl program copied from an online tutorial -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Tk;
my $mw = new MainWindow;
my $label = $mw -> Label(-text=>"Hello World") -> pack();
my $button = $mw -> Button(-text => "Quit", 
    -command => sub { exit })
-> pack();
MainLoop;
```

And then invoking from the command line -

```
./test.pl
```

I receive the following error -

```
[foo@localhost Desktop]$ ./test.pl 
1132148 is not a hash at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Tk/MainWindow.pm  line 53.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After commenting out lines it seems the error is generated by the "my $mw = " line

Googling the error message I'm finding references indicating it might be an X11 known issue but not sure.  Also not sure where to begin looking for an answer.

I have (using yum) double checked to make sure tk, perl-tk and tcl are up to date.  I've attempted to check the status of the X installation but am a little fearful of reinstalling lest I make things worse.

Comment: Could you provide a link to this online tutorial? Also what version of the Tk Perl module do you have?

Comment: Not that it solves your prolem but i can confirm that your code works on my installation of perl so from a syntax point of view what you have is ok.

Comment: The error message "is not a hash" is a non-standard error message, coming from the Tk module. If you google that, you will notice other people having the same problem. The message itself comes from some XS file https://metacpan.org/source/SREZIC/Tk-804.033/tkGlue.c#L1 which I cannot say more about because I do not know that language. Though it seems clear that this is probably an issue with your installation and not Perl.

Comment: The tutorial site is http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=922840 The versions are (per yum) Package perl-Tk-804.030-6.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:tk-8.5.13-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Not sure it's still relevant but I had the same problem a while ago. It seems to have to do with X11 color values being undefined, and can be fixed by running `xrdb`, e.g. `xrdb merge ~/.Xresources` with one of the files from [the Solarized project](https://github.com/solarized/xresources). No idea what the underlying problem is though.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from mbethke leads to what is the real problem with this specific error.
In fact, on Linux, you can quickly check if Tk is properly working or not by using the `wish` command (that should open a small window).

When you have the problem, wish does not open and outputs the following

```
unknown color name 'BACKGROUND'
```

And since wish and this error are more common than some Perl & Tk scripts, you can find more answers, such [this one](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1043686), in which one you find a way to clear the color defined :

```
xrdb -load /dev/null
xrdb -query
```

(`xrdb -query` is used to check the current color configuration.)

Then, everything should be fixed.